# Using Java locks for database concurrency

Tags: java, database, concurrency

I have the following scenario.
I have two tables. One stores multi values that are counters for transactions. Through a java application the first table value is read, incremented and written to the second table, as well as the new value being written back to the first table. Obviously there is potential for this to go wrong as it's a multiple user system.
My solution, in Java, to the issue is to provide Locks that have to, well *should*, be aquired before any action can be taken on either table. These Locks, ReentrantLocks, are static and there is one for each column in Table 1 as the values are completely independent of each other.

Is this a recommended approached?

Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No.** Use *implicit Database Locks*<sup>1</sup> for Database Concurrency. Relational databases support Transactions which are a vital part of [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID): use them.

Java-centric locks *will not work cross-VM* and as such will *not help* in multi-User/Server environments.

---

<sup>1</sup> Databases are smart enough to acquire/release locks to ensure Consistency and Isolation and may even use "lock free" implementations such as MVCC. There are *rare* occasions when explicit database locks must be requested, but this is an advanced use-case.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't very clear. The application will be running on a single JVM which users will be logging into.
If I am reading you correctly you are saying that it isn't needed and that the DB will do all he heavy lifting here

Comment: @Medu It may be needed for *other* reasons; however, I am a firm believer in that the database - a proper RDBMS - and access to it should be it's own guardian. There is also often an issue of sharing connections between threads: easiest is to not do it :)

Comment: Thanks for the input everyone, I believe you have steered me in the right direction. I was already using transaction, I just didn't realise that the DB would take care of the locking without any input hence the java 'hack'.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst agreeing with some of the sentiments of @pst's answer, I would say this depends slightly.

If the sequence of events is, and probably always will be, essentially "SQL oriented", then you may as well do the locking at the database level (and indeed, probably implicitly via the use of transactions).

However if there is, or you are planning to build in, **significant data manipulation logic within your app tier** (either generally or in the case of this specific operation), then locking at the app level may be more appropriate. (In reality, you will probably still run your SQL in transactions so that you're actually locking at both levels.)

I don't think the issue of multiple VMs is necessarily a compelling issue on its own for relying on DB-level locking. If you have multiple server apps accessing the database, you will in any case want to establish a well-defined protocol for which data is accessed concurrently under what circumstances. And in a system of moderate complexity, you will in any case want to build in a system of running periodic sanity checks on the data. (Even if your server apps are perfectly behaved 100% of the time, will back end tech support never ever ever have to run some miscellaneous SQL on the database outside your app...?)

Comment: It's not "locking" per-se at the DB level (locks are one method but there is also MVCC and such) that is the key; rather *using the DB properly guarantees ACID across clients/connections*. I up-voted for some points raised, although I *disagree* about the conclusion - database level transactions *support* heavy-weight code DALs (although there are alternatives to "large transactions" like optimistic concurrency, which still require transactions) - it's not quite the same debate as SProcs vs ORMS.